# Quite important concepts

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   1. Maybe Washington is major leader making economic system of America (10)
>   7. Uninitiated proposition to make Austen work (4)
>   9. A giant finally struck the last time (5)
>   10. Stone mineral supply (5)
>   11. For example, Elm Street is endless (4)
>   12. Speaker's reasonable price (4)
>   13. First woman seen inside extremely large bank (5)
>   14. Sing of retired evil creature working… (5)
>   16. …as characteristic person of all trades, without a fixed set showing restrictions (13)
>   19. Hawks reported identifying places for internees (5)
>   21. Catch girl with a bit of openness (5)
>   22. Powerful user of heartless mechanical helper (4)
>   23. Legend of siren losing flowery wreath (4)
>   24. Musketeer losing ring in a shoot-out (5)
>   25. Bestow upon Hugh an award (5)
>   26. Enthusiastic about institution not taking over beginners (4)
>   27. A saxophonist perhaps extremely deep in finish of sugar-coating (4,6)
>
> **Down**
>   1. Face on old UK banknotes: the Prince of Wales turned inward (7,6)
>   2. Meeting top leader in Pennsylvania Avenue residence's opening (7)
>   3. Covered by jackets, a team's recurring experience (5)
>   4. A quite important concept in music is to cover up voice leading mistakes (parallel fifths) (8)
>   5. Mythological beings are part of summer folklore (7)
>   6. Story notes regularly dismissed by Harry's agent (6,7)
>   8. Signify average of unfriendly type (4)
>   10. Dry wine for a brief instant (3)
>   15. Slow down certain actor (8)
>   17. A gambler's supporter (7)
>   18. Joy from reproduction of *Cats*? Yes. (7)
>   19. Piece of clothing made of carbon and cereal (4)
>   20. Acronymic Swedes' original song! (3, abbr.)
>   21. Extremely likable girl is not banned (5)

Comment: 20d is a very nice clue.

Comment: Should 6d be enumerated as two words?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Ah, you're right. I thought that's one word. Fixed now, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is the completed crossword

> [image]

Clue Explanations (thanks to Tom for figuring out the missing pieces in the comments)

> **Across**
>  1. CAPITAL + IS + M(ajor)
>  7. (l)EMMA
>  9.  AT LAS(t) (t is struck)
>  10. ST + ORE
>  11. s(TREE)t
>  12. Sounds like FAIR, price is the def.
>  13. EVE inside L(arg)E
>  14. (ORC)* + ON (figured out by Tom)
>  16. TRAIT + JACK inside inside SET + S
>  19. Sounds like SELLS (Hawks), places for internees is the def (thanks again to Tom).
>  21. LASS + O
>  22. RO(b)OT
>  23. LORE(lei)
>  24. anagram of A SHOOT without O
>  25. triple def
>  26. **I**nstitution **N**ot **T**aking **O**ver
>  27. (suga)R + (DEEP)* + LAYER
>
>  **Down**
>  1. CHARLES is the Prince of Wales + (INWARD)*
>  2. PA + L(eader) + AVE + R(esidence)
>  3. (jack)ETS A T(eam) <
>  4. INTER + V + (mist)A(kes) + (para)L(lel)
>  5. sum(MER FOLK)lore
>  6. TALE + N(o)T(e)S + POTTER
>  8. triple def
>  10. double def
>  15. STALL + ONE
>  17. A BETTOR
>  18. (CATS YES)*
>  19. C + OAT
>  20. S(wedes) O(riginal) S(ong), &lit refers to ABBA
>  21. L(ikabl)E + GAL

Comment: Not getting the anagram indicator in 27 A  rot13(Rkgerzryl QRRC pyhrf QC,  Fb jurer qb gur RR'f va gur nafjre pbzr sebz?)

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Yes, it made me pause alright but I couldn't see any other possibility than viewing "extremely" as an anagrind.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking  I was missing something.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Yeah, the intention there was to use "extremely" as an anagrind ("in a radical way", not "relating to outermost parts"). The [anagrind list](https://cryptics.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_anagram_indicators) I usually refer to doesn't contain that one, and it's often used as a different kind of indicator, so maybe it's not the best choice. Especially when there are so many to choose from.